# How to display "view" with XML file?

Tags: xml, laravel, laravel-blade

Oh, how ridiculously I formulated the question)) I’ll try in more detail.
I have a route:

```
Route::get('/parsers/settings/{id}', [AdminParserController::class, 'settings'])
   ->where('id', '[0-9]+')
   ->name('parsers::settings');
```

Then I select the required element from the XML file and convert it to a string:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($model->url);
$exampleElement = $xml;
foreach (explode("->", $model->path) as $prop) {
   $exampleElement = $exampleElement->$prop;
}
$exampleString = $exampleElement->asXML();

return view('admin.parser.settings', [
   'model' => $model,
   'exampleElement' => $exampleString,
]);
```

In view I display this element like this:

```
{{$exampleElement}}
```

And in the blade I want to display this element. Since this is a regular string, it is displayed incorrectly. I need to style the output somehow.

```
return response($exampleString, 200, [
   'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'
]);
```

If you do this, it will be displayed as it should. But I need to somehow transfer this to the view.

Comment: Does 'admin.parser.settings' have an XML prolog?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prettify the string returned by SimpleXML's `asXML()` you could load the string in DOMDocument and use it's `preserveWhiteSpace` and `formatOutput` parameters:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace

```
Do not remove redundant white space.
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.formatoutput

```
Nicely formats output with indentation and extra space.
```

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($model->url);
$exampleElement = $xml;
foreach (explode("->", $model->path) as $prop) {
   $exampleElement = $exampleElement->$prop;
}
$exampleString = $exampleElement->asXML();

$domDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$domDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$domDocument->formatOutput = true;
$domDocument->loadXML($exampleString);

$formattedString = $domDocument->saveXML();
```

Now in your view you should output `$formattedString` in a `pre` element:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

```
Represents preformatted text which is to be presented >exactly as written
```

```
<pre>{{ $formattedString }}</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

I understand that you're facing an issue with displaying the content of `$exampleElement`. If you want to display it in a browser for users to view, you can use the `<pre>` tag to preserve white spaces and line breaks like this:

```php
<pre>
    {{ $exampleElement }}
</pre>
```

If you need to use the actual value without escaping HTML tags (e.g., from `<p>some text` to `&lt;p&gt;some text`), you can use the `{!! !!}` syntax to print the variable like this:

```php
{!! $exampleElement !!}
```

### **UPDATE:**

if you also want to add `Content-Type: application/xml` header to you response from your view you can do it like this:

```php
$content = view('admin.parser.settings', [
   'model' => $model,
   'exampleElement' => $exampleString,
]);

return response($content)->header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
```

Comment: {!! $exampleElement !!} - This method seems to work a little) It separates the HTML tags as it should. But all these tags are visible only in the code. Only tag values are visible on the site page. And I need to display all the code on the site, both with tags and code values. How to do it? If I use (`return response($exampleString, 200, [
   'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'
]);`), it works as I need. You just need to apply it somehow to the blade.

Comment: @Rediska i updated the answer, check if solves your problem

Comment: In this case it gives the following error: `This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.`

Comment: I think he is outputting an HTML page and wants to display examples in XML in this page. The content type 'application/xml' does not match the HTML output.